# When the result value after API call is large data

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When the amount of data returned when calling API in "tryout" in API Manager is approximately 2MB, no result is displayed. The system is hanged or the system is not working. What values do I need to change or tune?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the APIM version you are using and what is the return data type?

Comment: @SarankiMagenthirarajah  Hi,  using 4.0.0 and return type is string(text)

Comment: Do you see an error in the Browser console or in the APIM logs?

Comment: @ycr, no error,  message only this "[2022-06-09 08:10:40,346]  INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after GLOBAL_TIMEOUT: 120 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
"   and still loading....  As the process continues, the UI is no longer available.

Comment: @SarankiMagenthirarajah, could you help me on this?